# How can I do array mapping with objectmapper?

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I have a response model that looks like this:

```
class ResponseModel: Mappable {

    var data: T?
    var code: Int = 0

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        data <- map["data"]
        code <- map["code"]
    }
}
```

If the json-data is not an array it works:

```
{"code":0,"data":{"id":"2","name":"XXX"}}
```

but if it is an array, it does not work

```
{"code":0,"data":[{"id":"2","name":"XXX"},{"id":"3","name":"YYY"}]}
```

My mapping code;

```
let apiResponse = Mapper<ResponseModel>().map(JSONObject: response.result.value)
```

For details;
I tried this code using this article : http://oramind.com/rest-client-in-swift-with-promises/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your declaration of data to an array, since that's how it is in the JSON:

```
var data: [T]?
```

Comment: but data sometimes object sometimes array. is there a way for both?

Comment: Create two separate mappable classes, one for an array and one without an array. Try mapping the first one and if it fails try the second one.

Comment: Also, the API should really wrap the object in an array object even when there is only one element.

Answer (score 15):

you need to use `mapArray` method instead of `map` :

```
let apiResponse = Mapper<ResponseModel>().mapArray(JSONObject: response.result.value)
```

Answer (score 4):

What I do is something like this:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    if let _ = try? map.value("data") as [Data] {
       dataArray <- map["data"]
    } else {
       data <- map["data"]
    }

    code <- map["code"]
}
```

where:

```
var data: T?
var dataArray: [T]?
var code: Int = 0
```

The problem with this is that you need to check both `data` and `dataArray` for nil values.

Answer (score 1):

```
let apiResponse = Mapper<ResponseModel>().mapArray(JSONObject: response.result.value)
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Anyone using SwiftyJSON and if you want an object from JSON directly without having a parent class, for example, you want the "data" from it. You can do something like this,

```
if let data = response.result.value {
   let json = JSON(data)
   let dataResponse = json["data"].object
   let responseObject = Mapper<DataClassName>().mapArray(JSONObject: dataResponse)
}
```

This will return you `[DataClassName]?` as response.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Abrahanfer's answer. I share my solution. I wrote a BaseResult for Alamofire.

```
class BaseResult<T: Mappable> : Mappable {

var Result : Bool = false
var Error : ErrorResult?
var Index : Int = 0
var Size : Int = 0
var Count : Int = 0
var Data : T?
var DataArray: [T]?

required init?(map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    Result  <- map["Result"]
    Error <- map["Error"]
    Index <- map["Index"]
    Size <- map["Size"]
    Count <- map["Count"]

    if let _ = try? map.value("Data") as [T] {
       DataArray <- map["Data"]
    } else {
       Data <- map["Data"]
    }
}}
```

The usage for Alamofire :

```
WebService.shared.request(url, params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, success: { (response : BaseResult<TypeData>) in

            if let arr = response.DataArray
            {
                for year in arr
                {
                   self.years.append(year)
                }
            }
        }, failure: {

        })
```

The request method is :

```
 func request<T: Mappable>(_ url: String,_ parameters: [String : Any] = [:], _ method: HTTPMethod = .post,_ httpHeaders: HTTPHeaders? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = JSONEncoding.default, success: @escaping (T) -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> () ) {

    AF.request(newUrl, method:method, parameters:parameters, encoding:encoding, headers: httpHeaders)

    .responseJSON { response in

        if let res = response.value {
            let json = res as! [String: Any]
            if let object = Mapper<T>().map(JSON: json) {
                success(object)
                return
            }
        }else if let _ = response.error {
            failure()
        }
    }
}
```

And TypeData class is :

```
class TypeData : Mappable
{
var Id : String = ""
var Title: String =  ""

required init(map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    Id  <- map["ID"]
    Title  <- map["YEAR"]
}}
```